# Landscape for only certain devices in iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

With iOS 8.0 in Xcode 6, there is nowhere where I can see that you can specify for each device if you want it portrait or landscape...

I want to have all iPhones only portrait except 6 Plus which should be both portrait and landscape. And I want all iPads to be both portrait and landscape.

Is there a way to do this or even a workaround it?

Comment: I think you will need to look into the new iOS 8 Rotation API and the `UITraitCollection` class. Then allow rotation based on the results. I've only seen the overview in `WWDC 2014 What's new in Cocoa Touch #202` and `WWDC 2014 Building Adaptive Apps With UIKit #216` but can't provide any code as I haven't coded anything using the new API. Documentation link to `UITraitCollection`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitSet_ClassReference/index.html .

Answer (score 2):

To make the 6+ different than other iPhones you'll need to implement `supportedInterfaceOrientations` something like this:

`- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (iPadOrPhonePlus()) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}`

I haven't settled on a way I like for that helper method but you can start with this:

`.#define iPadOrPhonePlus() ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) || [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] > 2)`

ignore the `.` before the #define SO was formatting it strangely without that.